# post-constructor calls many times

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces, ajax4jsf

in a brief word here is the problem 
when i value change of the menu it execute the post-constructor again in backing bean then execute method fillAreas and i used view scope  .

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="governate" value="#{add.selectedGovern}"  style="height:26px; text-align: right; width: 303px;"
                                                     valueChangeListener="#{add.fillAreas}" rendered="#{languageBean.isDefaultLanguage==true}" immediate="true" >  
                                        <f:selectItem itemLabel="---#{prompts._select} ---" itemValue="0"/>
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{add.governrateList}" var="govern" itemLabel="#{govern.governrateName}" itemValue="#{govern.governrateId}" />  
                                        <f:ajax  immediate="true"/>

                                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

what can i do to prevent calling post-constructor ? and if post-constructor called once why it called every time i select from menu ?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: By post-constructor, you mean the post-constructor of your `ViewScoped` bean?

Comment: yes by post-constructor of my ViewScoped bean .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A view scoped bean will be recreated on every single request when a property of it is been bound to an attribute of a taghandler (JSTL `<c:forEach>`, Facelets `<ui:include>`, JSF `<f:validateXXX>`, etc) or to the `binding` or `id` attribute of a JSF UI component (`<h:someComponent>`, etc).

This is related to [JSF issue 1492](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1492). You could solve it by disabling the partial state saving for the specific view, or by looking for alternate ways to achieve the desired functional requirement.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0 - `@ViewScoped` fails in taghandlers](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ViewScopedFailsInTagHandlers)